# How to select records which have date range with leap years?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table with struct like

```
ID | Name | StartDate | EndDate
```

How to select records which have date range, which contains leap years? For example, records, which have date range from 2011-01-01 (StartDate) to 2013-01-01  (EndDate)? This range contains leap years. I use MS SQL.

Thank you.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: At this point I haven't any idea, how to build this query...

Comment: do you mean to test if the range between StartDate and EndDate contains a leap year, or if StartDate or EndDate are leap years?

Comment: To test if the range between StartDate and EndDate contains a leap year.

Comment: Try starting with Select * from YourTableName.  Then start adding where clauses like "Where startdate >= '2011-01-01'".  Are you completely new to MS SQL?  If so, I recommend reading some articles on basics of MS SQL queries.  I think what Bob was trying to get at was, at least try something.  Don't just ask someone to do all of your work :-)

Comment: I didn't understood your humor. In this case I want to understand, what is "where cause" will be.

Comment: You should probably also define what exactly you want to check, just if any of the dates (e.g. 1.1 or 31.12) of the leap years is included in the date range or just that the 29th of February is included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a table `LeapYears`, then the query is simple as:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TableName t
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM LeapYears ly
   WHERE ly.[Date] >= StartDate AND ly.[Date] <= EndDate
)
```

To create a `LeapYear` table you could use this:

```
DECLARE @startYear int 
DECLARE @endYear int
SET @startYear = 2000
SET @endYear = 2030
CREATE  TABLE LeapYears(ID int IDENTITY(1,1), [Date] DATETIME)

DECLARE @currentYear int
SET @currentYear = @startYear
WHILE @currentYear <= @endYear
BEGIN
  DECLARE @yearStr char(4)
  SELECT @yearStr = CAST(@currentYear AS char(4))
  IF ISDATE(@yearStr + '0229') = 1  
     INSERT INTO LeapYears VALUES(@yearStr + '0229')
  SET @currentYear = @currentYear + 1
END
```

The script creates these records:

```
ID  Date
1   2000-02-29 00:00:00.000
2   2004-02-29 00:00:00.000
3   2008-02-29 00:00:00.000
4   2012-02-29 00:00:00.000
5   2016-02-29 00:00:00.000
6   2020-02-29 00:00:00.000
7   2024-02-29 00:00:00.000
8   2028-02-29 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you to write one stored procedure that receives the two datetime and verify if each year of period is leap year. To do this you can simple do year mod 4 = 0.